# Making a live search function

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, phpmyadmin, crud

I've made a crud function where users register/log in to view their own contact list. The mysql database has tables of details such as `name`, `mobile`, `email`, `company`, `title` etc. I want to implement a live search function where the user can type in something such as e.g. first `name + title` or whatever random combination, and for the live search to be able to match the search field(s).

What is your recommendation in making something that fulfills the above?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $result = array();
    $Query = "SELECT * FROM contact_list  WHERE ";
    $keyword = preg_split("/[\s,-]+/", $q);
        $flag = 0;

        while ($flag<count($keyword))
        {
            if($flag==0)
                $Query.="  name LIKE '%".$keyword[$flag]."%' OR title LIKE '%".$keyword[$flag]."%'";
            else
                $Query.=" OR name LIKE '%".$keyword[$flag]."%' OR title LIKE '%".$keyword[$flag]."%'";
            $flag++;
        }
        $Query .= " ORDER BY `name` ASC";

        $exec = $this->db->query($Query);
        foreach ($exec->result() as $row)
        {
            array_push($result,$row);
        }
```

This code i have done in codigniter. you can change it as you needed.. i hope this is you want.